# Change object position dynamically using objectAnimator

Tags: android, translation, objectanimator

I am trying out something and my aim is to move a button to a specific point on the screen. I have calculated the `y`-coordinate of the new position, then `moveOn` is called to update the position of the button.

The problem I have is that, after every call, button first returns to its initial position before moving. Please help a newbie.

```
public void moveOn() {
    ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(button, "translationY", translation_value);
}
```

Comment: Try using constraint layout's ConstraintSet.[This](https://android.jlelse.eu/build-awesome-animations-with-7-lines-of-code-using-constraintlayout-854e8fd3ad93) one can be useful.

Comment: Thanks I got a solution with setX and setY.